# Form with a horizontal part and a vertical part

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using boostrap and `simple_form` I have a large form that I would like part of the form to be horizontal and the other part vertical ie

```
<%= simple_form_for( @vehicle, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } %>
```

Is there a way to do both on the same form? Through partials maybe?

Comment: Ambiguous Title though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question has nothing to do with `ruby-on-rails` itself. This is a css problem.
If you look at twitter bootstrap css code, you can see that the behavior of the horizontal/vertical inputs and labels on a form, are related to the `control-group` divs.
So you can create this `divs` manually, and set the apropriate class to it.

```
<form> // Your form, without classes
  <div class='form-horizontal'> // A div for the horizontal ones.
  </div>
  <div> // A div for the vertical ones.
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks MurifoX it worked perfectly. I removed the class from the form and applied it only to the applicable divs.